# Get extended class's name

Tags: ruby

Given the following:

```
class Animal
  def self.info
    "This is the class '#{self.class.to_s}', and the available breeds are #{BREEDS.to_s}"
  end
end

class Dog < Animal
  BREEDS = %w(x y z)
end
```

When i call:

```
Dog.info
=> This is the class 'Class'
```

I'm expecting `Dog` instead of `Class`, how can i get the current class name from Animal without putting `info` in the `Dog` class.

Also, i get `undefined constant Animal::BREEDS`

What am i missing?

Comment: Well, `hello` is a class method. You haven't created an instance of `Dog`, hence there aren't any owners.

Comment: Jack i revamped the sample code to make more sense, I'm not using instances in this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.to_s`, not `self.class.to_s`. You are already "inside" `self` in `Animal`

To access the constant:  `self::BREEDS`

So:

```
class Animal
  def self.info
    "This is the class '#{self.to_s}', and the available breeds are #{self::BREEDS.to_s}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Zabba! That's exactly what i wanted :)